# Adding icons to text in Rails html.slim

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, icons, slim-lang

So I am styling the website and trying to add icons next to the text. 
Icons are used from Fontawesome.
I understand that icons should be added in html.slim, (as there is no respective HTML file). What I tried was adding

```
i.fa fa-user-circle.left
```

to the code ("fa fa-user-circle" being the icon from fontawesome)

```
.row.form-group
 .col-sm-12
   = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, placeholder: t('element_names.email_address'), class: "form-control"
    i.fa fa-user-circle.left
```

I am clearly missing something as icon is not appearing.

Looking to achieve something similar to this: https://pasteboard.co/HJKCkJg.png

Comment: I'm not familiar with rails and slim lang, but if your goal is to assign all three `fa fa-user-click left` classes to `i` element, I think you have a typo. You probably should write it as `i.fa.fa-user-circle.left`

Comment: Thanks, it seems like I am one step closer, as removing the space at least placed the icon: https://pasteboard.co/HJL9KK1.png    Now all I need is figuring out how to place it into the right location there

Comment: You can try to move the icon to be above the email_field. Then just adjust the CSS positioning.

Comment: Yes, I can work with css to position it, but I need to at least place it into the same line as otherwise it creates unnecessary space.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bulma framework and just put a icon inside a span tag, something like this, and apply some bulma css class:

```
form method="post" action="/login"
  .columns.is-mobile
    .column
      .title.is-4 Login
        .field.control.has-icons-left.has-icons-right
           input.input.is-primary type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"
           span.icon.is-small.is-left: i.fas.fa-user
```

[Input username with icon][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXJMm.png